# What is the formal/polite way to begin and end an email in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, formal

In English, formal emails, e.g. emails to a professor, often start with "Hi", "Hello", "Dear" followed by the receiver's name (and title, if applicable). The ending is usually "Best", "Regards", "Sincerely" followed by the writer's name. Does Chinese have similar constructs? Or does it have more/less strict rules?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The traditional Chinese letter is very complex.It has many honorifics that vary greatly for different receivers.

But today,most people's traditional education is insufficient to write these letter.

For email,people tend to write simply and practicably。

**Habitual formation。**

[image]

example:

```
周老师：
    您好！
    我是Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a...
    这个Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna a...
    敬祝！
安康！

                                                       学生 Jacob  敬上
                                                       2015.04.10
```

example 2:

```
陈英俊先生 道鉴
    去年入先生门下，承蒙恩师言传身教，宿愿得偿。中文潦草，敬启夫子。
     。。。。。。
     。。。。。。。。
     。。。。。。。。。。。

    敬请
 教安 
                                                        授业  张三顿首
                                                        乙未 二月廿二
```

Comment: Is your formatting, particularly the indentation, a style or a rule? Also, is example 2 what you referred to as a traditional letter? I can hardly understand any of it...Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @ThomasHsieh It can be treat as a style  at present.But many  people  prefer stick to the formation，especially in formal letters。Example 2 uses some traditional words, not widely used nowadays。

Comment: +1 for the lorem ipsum

Answer (score 9):

I will give you a example, explanation in the brackets, see if it's useful to you.

this is a email I sent to my client, I think this format is kind of formal

```
  孔经理：(he's a manager, and his family name is Kong, it's impolite to call    somebody's name in a formal letter)

  blablabla

  此致(this word means "I finish my word here" or "this is the end of this letter", you should always use this word as an ending word in a personal letter or )

  My name

 2015.xx.xx
```

Hope it's helpful

此致

Answer (score -1):

安康！(ankang)) means 'may you enjoy of a good health'; seems rather correct for a final salutation inside an email. Specialists can tell much better of course.