# How to end an email asking for permission from my boss in Chinese?

Tags: formal, politeness

I need to ask my boss permission to move forward with a project.  I am sending him an email, but I'm not sure how to close the email.  I understand that it is common to wish health and happiness, etc. (See [this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-is-the-formal-polite-way-to-begin-and-end-an-email-in-chinese) question), for example:

- 敬祝！安康！
- 祝你一切都好！

But I would like to also convey my appreciation if he seriously considers my ideas. Is there also a way to say something like, "Thank you for your time", or "Thank you for your consideration"? Is "谢谢您的考虑" something people say?

Comment: Well, for an email, you don't have to be so serious. In my opinion, following the formal format of Chinese letters in an email looks quite weird. So, just say what you want to convey with a polite, humble tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **[敬上](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=DzxzHB-URGXf51zLAeCGYVxZa2exXbt-e9DujDkv7gzuqTde8tGH7vERdM0sU4ZXqNappxdCSW7Kh0Gjh7wWQa)**

> 书信
>
> 古代用于书信结尾的敬语或谦词，表示对收信人的尊敬。现多见于日语。
>
> 用法：
>
> ......（正文）
>
> xxx（写信人）
>
> 敬上

I've received many messages set-up this way. "Thank you for your time" or "Thank you for your consideration" are very English-isms, you're best just to go with the Chinese way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Never got a job but, can't you include your concern in the text of the mail?
Like
我这个项目发展到现在，做得很好。不知你是否认为现在是继续发展这个项目的好机会？
祝好
xxx...